# Available Wifi connections list by using list view in Xmamrin

Tags: xamarin.android, wifi, xamarin.forms, wifimanager

i just want to know that if it is possible to make listview for the available wifi connections by using xamarin.....And if it is possible then please help me out here...... step by step.

Comment: Please read the documentation https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Net.Wifi/

Comment: There is also this and it is very simple to use: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Connectivity/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is. took it from xamarin forum: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27364/how-to-get-list-of-wifi-networks

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net.Wifi;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace NetworkLocation.Utility
{
    public class Wifi
    {
        private Context context = null;
        private static WifiManager wifi;
        private WifiReceiver wifiReceiver;
        public static List<string> WiFiNetworks;

        public Wifi(Context ctx)
        {
            this.context = ctx;
        }



   public void GetWifiNetworks()
    {
        WiFiNetworks = new List<string>();

    // Get a handle to the Wifi
    wifi = (WifiManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);

    // Start a scan and register the Broadcast receiver to get the list of Wifi Networks
    wifiReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
    context.RegisterReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.ScanResultsAvailableAction));
    wifi.StartScan();
}

    class WifiReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            IList<ScanResult> scanwifinetworks = wifi.ScanResults;
            foreach(ScanResult wifinetwork in scanwifinetworks)
            {
                WiFiNetworks.Add(wifinetwork.Ssid);
            }
        }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried but it is not working because i want the list of wifi networks to be in listview.i just copied it and pasted it in my code and changed the listview name with my listview name and it was not working.help me out here how i can use this with my own code...it is just simple i want to show available networks in my own list view.

Comment: i am building this application in xamarin.android but it should not be the problem because when i changed the listview name with my listview name and run the code then it was showing the null exception.......my guess is that the receiver is not working. Null exception will only occurs when list view is empty in my case. But when this code runs the list view should be populated with the networks???????

Comment: and i am not using emulator this code will not work on emulator correctly.i am using my device to check whether its working or not.